# Remove beginnings of email addresses from text using grep or sed

Tags: shell-script, regex, grep, sed

I have a text file with lines like the following:

> John Stevenson Johnnyboy34 john.stevenson@company.com 0320423\n
>   Mike Anderson AndersMike mike@mikeltd.foo 0234234

How do I remove the "text" part from email addresses, like this: [text]@company.foo but keep the file unaltered besides that?

Comment: You would like to remove the local part of the email, do I understand correctly?

Comment: The beginning part before the @ sign. I am unsure if it's called "local part"

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
echo -e John Stevenson Johnnyboy34 john.stevenson@company.com 0320423\\n Mike Anderson AndersMike mike@mikeltd.foo 0234234 | sed -r -e 's/((\w|[.])+)@/@/g'
```

Which yields:

```
John Stevenson Johnnyboy34 @company.com 0320423
 Mike Anderson AndersMike @mikeltd.foo 0234234
```